# Optimising determination of $\pi$ by random walks

Tags: random-walk, pi, monte-carlo

I'm writing a random number generator test.  The kit it will run on is way less powerful than a desktop PC, and I've come across this wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Monte_Carlo_methods) for determining $\pi$.  I'm interested in the random walk method, utilising this formula:

[image: Pi by random walk folrmula]

There is also this explanatory graph with an example 5 walks of 200 steps each:

[image: 5 Random walks]

So I perform some number (n) of random walks of length L.  If the generator is working correctly, I will calculate Pi to some accuracy approaching the true value. In this example, I will have used 5 * 200 = 1000 random numbers.  So let's say that nL = 1000.  My test will probably use about 1,000,000 random numbers.

The question is: what is the optimum value of n and L so that nL = 1,000,000 to get the best accuracy for calculating Pi?  This will directly correlate to the quality of the random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That formula on Wikipedia is pretty misleading. That is not a limit, in fact, it is an equation: $$\pi={2n\over (E|W_n|)^2}={2\over (E|Z|)^2},$$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. So your estimator for $\pi$ will simply be 
$$\widehat\pi={2\over \left({1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n |Z_j|\right)^2},$$
where $(Z_j)_{j=1}^n$ is a random sample of standard normal values.

Comment: So what would the values of n & L be as to maximize the potential for accurately calculating Pi when nL = 1,000,000?

Comment: @PaulUszak  Take $n=1000000$ and $L=1$. The length of the random walk is completely irrelevant.